# Java HDFS listStatus: AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I'm trying to list files from Name Node.
My application is run at Data Node with following Hdfs configuration:

```
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf");
  config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
  config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
  config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
  config.set("fs.file.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem");
  config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
  UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("kt_user@QA.DF.SBRF.COM",
    "kt_user.keytab");
  UserGroupInformation user = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();
  System.out.println("SU " + user.toString());

  System.out.println("Current userName: " + UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getUserName());

  hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
```

Additionally I set the javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly system property value to false:
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

The FileSystem instance is created successfully.
"SU" is kt_user@QA.DF.SBRF.COM (auth KERBEROS). "Current userName:" is kt_user@QA.DF.SBRF.COM

The principal is correct. I check it by command "klist".

The keytab-file is located at the same directory as jar (/home/user)

But when I run hdfs.listStatus(new Path("some real path")) is return:

```
 org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

What am I doing wrong?

By Kerberos Debug I found the the following Error-message:

```
 error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
```

Comment: How do you run the code? You may have to add a JVM flag to the process on the CLI, not use `System.setProperty`, which only runs on the driver node of mapreduce

Comment: I run it with java -jar.  I also tried to do it with "-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf" argument.

Comment: OneCricketeer, I updated my question with more error information:  "error Message is Additional pre-authentication required"

Comment: Not sure. Haven't used Kerberos in years. You've showed kinit is working, and klist shows the ticket, so there's some Java / file misconfiguration. For example, check user permissions on the keytab file?

Comment: I checked: the user has all permissions for keytab